# CSS configuring scroll NOT to be smooth / continuous, but every first item always seem full

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page, with a Div, with plenty of spans inside, each with a piece of text. All Spans togheter are  like several pages long, like ling file list on windows explorer. Each Div is like two text lines.

Scrolling with mouse or keyboard produce this “smooth” scroll, or pixel-scroll, like any webpage, normal behiviour.

I would like to simulate the "top-div-always-show-full", like in Windows explorer, to say again, where a scroll down moves all the list exactly one "span" position, and not a number of pixels.

This can be seen also like the interfaces from the 80s, that scroll goes on span height aways so looks like spans moving up and down and not a flow-list.

Could it be possible to configure the dvi scroll in such a way that each span, which ever, is always on top fully shown??

It seems to be something similar to :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type
but that affect also mouse scrolling, and donot show the "flow" inbetween

Comment: Please provide more information so that others can understand your question.

Comment: Not sure how to explain. Maybe ...   Normaly the scroll works as pixel by pixel, i turn the mouse whell a bit, scroll moves 12 pixels, a bit more, move another 12, or show.   What I am loking for is like moving span by span. Like "toc-toc-toc", that wise I say like in the 80s.

Comment: Somebody helps me to explain ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my english is not so good, sorry, some code may help?

Comment: Maybe this help, scrolling in most web page, content goes up pixels by pixels, so DIVs & TextLines get cutted up as it goes. But scrolling on file list in windows explorer goes ONE-LINE-AT-A-TIME, so always shows full height items.  

thatwise, when scrolling with items of similar names, looks like the "name changes", and it is easier to spot diferences. 

may this help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.